# Keep pathlib.(Posix)Path patched by pyfakefs when subclassing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, pathlib, pyfakefs

I have subclassed `PosixPath` this way:

```
from pathlib import PosixPath


class Node(PosixPath):

    def __new__(cls, *args, mykwarg=None, **kwargs):
        self = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        self._mykwarg = mykwarg
        return self
```

and added several `@property` methods.

Now if I want to test it (I use `pytest`), it does not work:

```
def test_Node(fs):
    fs.create_file('simple.txt')
    n = Node('simple.txt')
    n.stat()
```

Running the test outputs (at line `n.stat()`):

```
E   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'simple.txt'
```

what is not completely unexpected, as, I guess, only `PosixPath` is patched by `pyfakefs`, but not my own class, even if it inherits from `PosixPath`.

But I'd liked to be able to test my class while keeping the features of `pyfakefs`. Have the methods, fields etc. inherited from `PosixPath` still patched by `pyfakefs` as is `PosixPath`, and only have the properties I did add not patched. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Node` is derived from `PosixPath` at load time, while `pathlib` is not patched yet, and it will not be patched because patching is done by module name. If you want to have it derived from the patched `PosixPath`, the class definition has to be reloaded *after* patching started. As you are using `pytest`, the best way is probably to write your own fixture that does that:

```py
import pytest
from pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest import Patcher
import node  # assuming Node lives in node.py

@pytest.fixture
def my_fs():
    with Patcher(modules_to_reload=[node]) as p:
        yield p.fs

def test_Node(my_fs):
    ...
```

The [modules_to_reload](http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/usage.html#modules-to-reload) argument is there exactly for this kind of problems.

*Disclaimer*: I'm a contributor to pyfakefs.